# After pulling data from an API, I am having trouble splitting the data into more columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I pulled data from an API. I converted the data into two data frames to more easily split the columns. However, I am unable to split the `ticker_sentiment` into multiple columns in `df3`.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=NEWS_SENTIMENT&topics=technology,ipo&apikey=demo"
data2 = requests.get(url)
r = json.loads(data2.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(r)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df.feed)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.ticker_sentiment.convert_dtypes(convert_string = True))
print(df3)
```

What I tried is at the top. I was expecting df3 table to hold more columns: ticker, relevant_score, etc.

Comment: provide examples of the data so that users can reproduce the problem. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IIUC:

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=NEWS_SENTIMENT&topics=technology,ipo&apikey=LC7M8GMLMYVOLL6O"
with requests.Session() as request:
    response = request.get(url=url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(response.raise_for_status())

data = response.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data.get("feed"),
    meta=["title", "url", "time_published", "authors", "summary", "banner_image",
          "source", "category_within_source", "source_domain", "overall_sentiment_score",
          "overall_sentiment_label"],
    record_path="ticker_sentiment"
)
print(df.head())
```

output:

```
  ticker relevance_score ticker_sentiment_score ticker_sentiment_label                                                                                  title                                                                                                  url   time_published              authors                                                                                              summary                                                                                         banner_image             source category_within_source              source_domain overall_sentiment_score overall_sentiment_label
0   META        0.047185               0.071975                Neutral                  7 IPOs this week but don't make these 10 mistakes in pursuit of gains  https://www.business-standard.com/finance/personal-finance/7-ipos-this-week-but-don-t-make-these...  20230628T055910  [Business Standard]  The most common mistake than investors make that can be a trap and hinder your financial success...  https://bsmedia.business-standard.com/_media/bs/img/article/2022-11/14/full/1668449058-6907.jpg?...  Business Standard                Finance  www.business-standard.com                0.132975                 Neutral
1   SHOP         0.03746                0.12748                Neutral                                                                       A Tale of 2 IPOs                                          https://www.fool.com/investing/2023/09/28/a-tale-of-2-ipos/  20230928T152900  [Motley Fool Staff]  There's plenty to learn from the Instacart and Klaviyo IPOs, even if you're staying away from th...                                  https://g.foolcdn.com/misc-assets/hp-sa-cumulative-growth-chart.png        Motley Fool                    n/a               www.fool.com                0.213028        Somewhat-Bullish
2   META        0.009368               0.033494                Neutral                                                                       A Tale of 2 IPOs                                          https://www.fool.com/investing/2023/09/28/a-tale-of-2-ipos/  20230928T152900  [Motley Fool Staff]  There's plenty to learn from the Instacart and Klaviyo IPOs, even if you're staying away from th...                                  https://g.foolcdn.com/misc-assets/hp-sa-cumulative-growth-chart.png        Motley Fool                    n/a               www.fool.com                0.213028        Somewhat-Bullish
3  DSSMY        0.220141               0.215018       Somewhat-Bullish  IPO market shows fatigue as trio of big tech deals languish in second week of trading  https://www.marketwatch.com/story/ipo-market-shows-fatigue-as-trio-of-big-tech-deals-languish-in...  20230925T160400      [Ciara Linnane]  The initial public offering market was again showing signs of fatigue on Monday, with the three ...                                                             https://images.mktw.net/im-857425/social        MarketWatch            Top Stories        www.marketwatch.com                0.093542                 Neutral
4   GOOG        0.147818               -0.06862                Neutral  IPO market shows fatigue as trio of big tech deals languish in second week of trading  https://www.marketwatch.com/story/ipo-market-shows-fatigue-as-trio-of-big-tech-deals-languish-in...  20230925T160400      [Ciara Linnane]  The initial public offering market was again showing signs of fatigue on Monday, with the three ...                                                             https://images.mktw.net/im-857425/social        MarketWatch            Top Stories        www.marketwatch.com                0.093542                 Neutral
```